# If $variable is "string" then echo "stri"?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a class for a table td based on the string that is outputted within it.

```
<?php echo '<td class="'?>

<?php 
    if ($day === 'monday') 
        echo 'mon';
    if ($day === 'tuesday') 
        echo 'tues';
?>

<?php echo '">' . $day . '</td>'
```

However this results in the following:

```
<td class>monday</td>
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
<td class="mon">monday</td>
<td class="tues">tuesday</td>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made sure that `$day` is actually either `'monday'` or `'tuesday'`?

Comment: If you can control the css, you could change the classes to `mon` and `tue`, that way, the class value will be `<?= substr($day, 0, 3) ?>` and you won't need any if-else.

Comment: Holy scuffed new shoes! Can I please get an answer that at least *looks* maintainable?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend deciding on the class beforehand to make the code more readable.

```
<?php
    $class = '';

    if ($day === 'monday') {
        $class = 'mon';
    } else if ($day === 'tuesday') {
        $class = 'tues';
    }
?>

<td class="<?= $class ?>"><?= $day ?></td>
```

Comment: `<?=` works only if shortags are enabled, correct?

Comment: That is correct. If not enabled `<?=` should be replaced with `<?php echo`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it would be to use a switch statement:

```
$day = 'tuesday';
switch ($day) {
    case 'monday':
        $shortDay = 'mon';
        break;
    case 'tuesday':
        $shortDay = 'tues';
        break;
    default:
        $shortDay = 'invalid';
}
echo '<td class="' . $shortDay . '">' . $day . '</td>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, yes, that was a typo, I've corrected that now but still getting the same problem.

Comment: The `elseif`, although better, is not required here.

Comment: @Jack what do you mean? It's not valid syntax if you don't have the `else if`

Comment: @sachleen His code just had two separate `if` statements; I don't see the invalid syntax.

Comment: @Jack oh you're right, I must have deleted it when I was breaking it up into multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the condition from the tag - makes it less error prone, maintainable, ...

```
<?php 
   $shortday = '';
   if ($day === 'monday') 
      $shortday = 'mon';
   else if($day === 'tuesday')
      $shortday = 'tues';
   else if...

   echo "<td class=\"$shortday\">$day</td>";

?>
```

Comment: Your final echo statement either needs string concat or single quotes around the class value.

Comment: Concatenation with what? I didn't see where?

Comment: You've fixed it now. Your previous version was broken.

Answer (score 1):

I like xbonez and codingbiz answers, but if you access to the style sheet and can change it you could rename the classes so that they are called using the first 3 letters of the day and then just:

```
echo ('<td class="' . substr($day, 0, 3) . '">' . $day . '</td>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with values for each of the `<tr>` lines in your code. Then loop through them. This will be the cleanest method. It's also a good practice for if you would have many more values of preknown items (like perhaps days of the month).

```
$days = array( 'mon' => 'monday',
               'tue' => 'tuesday',
               'wed' => 'wednesday'
             );

foreach($days as $k => $v) {
    echo '<td class="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</td>';
}
```